# dplyr: Calculate account balance per day

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to plot a forecast of an account's balance but I am struggling with calculating the daily balance using dplyr.  What does not work is this approach using dplyr::lag as lag does not see the mutated value:

```
my_balance <- 100
df <- data.frame(day = 1:10, cost = c(-20,-30,-10,-30,-40,-20,-30,-35,-10,-12), revenue = c(100,20,0,12,7,100,20,30,15,12))
df %>%
  mutate(balance = lag(balance, default = my_balance) + cost + revenue)
```

Result:

```
   day cost revenue balance
1    1  -20     100     180
2    2  -30      20      90
3    3  -10       0      90
4    4  -30      12      82
5    5  -40       7      67
6    6  -20     100     180
7    7  -30      20      90
8    8  -35      30      95
9    9  -10      15     105
10  10  -12      12     100
```

Expected result:

```
   day cost revenue balance
1    1  -20     100     180
2    2  -30      20     170
3    3  -10       0     160
4    4  -30      12     142
5    5  -40       7     109
6    6  -20     100     189
7    7  -30      20     179
8    8  -35      30     174
9    9  -10      15     179
10  10  -12      12     179
```

What can I use to create a balance per row using the previous calculated sum?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cumsum()` of `cost + revenue` added to `my_balance`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(balance = my_balance + cumsum(cost + revenue))
#>    day cost revenue balance
#> 1    1  -20     100     180
#> 2    2  -30      20     170
#> 3    3  -10       0     160
#> 4    4  -30      12     142
#> 5    5  -40       7     109
#> 6    6  -20     100     189
#> 7    7  -30      20     179
#> 8    8  -35      30     174
#> 9    9  -10      15     179
#> 10  10  -12      12     179
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I did play around with cumsum but looks like I was too tired to get this right!